# Absolutely positioned child div going out of parent div

Tags: html, css

In my case an absolutely positioned child element `carouselbuttonCntainer` is going far some pixels below parent div `bgCoverSection` when I set it's bottom value as zero.

HTML:

```
  <div class="bgCoverSection" id="homePageSection">
    <div id="carouselbuttonCntainer">
      <div id="carouselbuttonInnerCntainer">
        <input type="radio" class="imageCarouselRadioButton" 
        name="imageCarouselRadioButton" checked="checked">
        <input type="radio" class="imageCarouselRadioButton" 
        name="imageCarouselRadioButton">
        <input type="radio" class="imageCarouselRadioButton" 
        name="imageCarouselRadioButton">
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
   //parent
  .bgCoverSection{
    height: 614px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: aqua;
    text-align: center;
  }
  //child
  #carouselbuttonCntainer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;    
  }
  .imageCarouselRadioButton{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
   }
```

In the code above code I set `carouselbuttonCntainer` bottom to 0, it's bottom doesn't align with bottom of parent `bgCoverSection`.

But when I set `carouselbuttonCntainer` top to 0, it's top will align with top of parent `bgCoverSection`.

Comment: Set relative position for parent and also It seems you need to set `vertical-alignment` for those elements.

Comment: If you want absolute positioned child to be affected by parent, set `position: relative` to parent element

Comment: the position absolute will set your element at absolute position with respect to the window, i.e. at left-top by default. Since you are providing the left and bottom it will position it at the bottom of screen with 50% space on left. If you want to position it with respect of the parent div, you should use the position as relative. This is also recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to provide `position: relative;` to parent when ever you use `position: absolute;`.

In your case please add `position:relative` to this class `.bgCoverSection`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: relative` to its parent div.

```
.bgCoverSection{
  height: 614px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: aqua;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent position as relative it would-be working